# role="presentation" on button not working in firefox and internet explorer

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have the below html structure

```
<ul role="presentation" >
  <li>
    <button aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" ng-click="onButtonClick()"> Edit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Even though the attribute `role="presentation"` is there, still the screen reader is able to read the edit button in Firefox and Internet Explorer. It's fine in Google Chrome though. Please tell what what is wrong with the above HTML snippet.

Comment: Will it work if you set `tabindex=-1`  on the `button`.  I can't test it right now myself.

Comment: @t.niese we can set but the problem is that even the normal users would not be able to access using keyboard, we want to prevent the screen reader from reading it

Comment: An element that is visible and focusable by keyboard for a _normal_  user but hidden from screen reader is imho conflicting with the ARII specs. What is the reason why you don't want to give people with screen-readers the ability to use/see the edit button?

Comment: as when the keyboard user clicks on the button ,he will get access to items which cannot be accessible without using the mouse, hence we want to disable the total functionality by making it invisible from screen reader

Comment: I might be wrong but setting `aria-expanded="false"` on the container (`<li>`)  should at least be valid and hide the content from the screen-reader.

Comment: I tried that t.niese, somehow it is not working

Comment: t.niese, yes, sorry, you are wrong :-)  the aria tags are for passing semantic information to assistive technology but they don't add (or remove) any actual behavior for the element.  you can set aria-expanded='false' but all that's doing is telling the screen reader that something is collapsed. it's typically used on an element that can be expanded or collapsed, such as an accordion section, combobox dropdown, menu list, tree branch, etc.  it doesn't cause anything to be "hidden" from the screen reader.

Comment: however, t.niese, you are right in your answer section (below) in that the solution in this case is to not break the aria rules regarding setting role='presentation' on a focusable object.  having ie, ff, and chrome behave differently is correct behavior because it's undefined behavior.  balaji, you can fix the problem by removing the role and aria-hidden properties.  perhaps re-post with a question on how to solve the ui you're trying to develop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now more a comment then an answer because it does not contain a solution.

I would say Firefox and IE are right because the specs say

> If an element with a role of presentation is focusable, user agents MUST ignore the normal effect of the role and expose the element with implicit native semantics

In addition [2.4 Fourth rule of ARIA use](https://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/):

> Do not use `role="presentation"` or `aria-hidden="true"` on a visible **focusable** element .
>
> Using either of these on a visible **focusable** element will result in some users focusing on 'nothing'.
>
> Do **not** do this:
>
> ```
> <button role=presentation>press me</button>
> ```
>
> Do **not** do this:
>
> ```
>  <button aria-hidden="true">press me</button>
> ```
>
> Note: If an interactive element cannot be seen or interacted with, then you can apply aria-hidden, for example:
>
> ```
>   button {visibility:hidden}
>
>   <button aria-hidden="true">press me</button>
> ```

Comment: Hi, +1 for the detailed explanation, thanks for that , is there any workaround in ie and firefox

Comment: Hey t.niese, I found a workaround for this by adding aria-label="blank", then on tab event it is reading blank in all the browsers. If I hover, it is saying "press me" in firefox and ie  and in chrome it is saying "blank", can we make chrome to behave in the same way as ff and ie by saying "press me" instead of "blank"

Answer (score 1):

I think its reading because its visible to reader. Have you tried aria-hidden="true" in the button?

Comment: Hi yesarpit, thanks for your reply, I have tried with aria-hidden="true", Please find my edited code.